# My carousel is not working with filtered images, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gg2k8kw7/

I spent all weekend looking at code, took a break but still... can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. My project is due very soon, so I need to finish this and my head is about to explode!
 What I'm trying to do: 
- Make filtered images; 
- Carousel with navigators on the side. 

What am I doing wrong? I have no idea anymore and I'm desperate. Thank you everybody for all the help you have given me growing into the completion of my studies and begin of my career! Even with all dificulties, I won't give up.

Much love.

```
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */

// TESTING SOME MORE GALLERY LAYOUTS, THE NEVER ENDING HOPE


jQuery(function($){
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    modal: true,
    helpers : { buttons: { } }
  });
  $(".filter").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    // if we click the active tab, do nothing
    if (!$this.hasClass("active")) {
      $(".filter").removeClass("active");
      $this.addClass("active"); // set the active tab
      var $filter = $this.data("rel"); // get the data-rel value from selected tab and set as filter
      $filter == 'all' ? // if we select "view all", return to initial settings and show all
        $(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery").not(":visible").fadeIn() 
        : // otherwise
        $(".fancybox").fadeOut(0).filter(function () { 
          return $(this).data("filter") == $filter; // set data-filter value as the data-rel value of selected tab
        }).attr("data-fancybox-group", $filter).fadeIn(1000); // set data-fancybox-group and show filtered elements
    } // if
  }); // on
}); // ready
jQuery(function(e){var t,n,r,i=navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i)?true:false;if(!document.referrer==""){if(document.referrer.indexOf(location.protocol+"//"+location.host)===0){n=true}}if(history.length==0&&i||history.length==1&&!i){t=false}else{t=true}if(t){if(n){r='<a class="button" href="'+document.referrer+'"> &larr; Voltar à pagina anterior </a>'}else{r='<a class="button" href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript: history.go(-1)"> &larr; Voltar à pagina anterior </a>'}e(r).appendTo("#wrap")}})

$(function() {
  var selectedClass = "";
  $(".fil-cat").click(function() {
    selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
    $("#portfolio").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
    $("#portfolio div").not("." + selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("." + selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
      $("#portfolio").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, 300);

  });
});

// Apply click handler to all tile elements,
$('.tile').click(function(){
   // Get image inside tile element
  var img = $(this).find('img');
  // Update modal with image data
  $("#img01").attr('src', img.attr('src'));
  $('#caption').html(img.attr('alt'));
  $('#myModal').css('display','block');
});

// Close modal
$('.close').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').css('display','none');
})

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
modal.addEventListener('click',function(){
this.style.display="none";
})
```

Comment: fancybox plugin files are not added.

Comment: thank you! Just updated fiddle, seems like slideshow works now, thanks! Only the buttons issue left